# Using grep, sed or awk to find words in between? I want to be able to extract the package name until .el7

Tags: bash, grep, sed, awk

I am writing a script (bash/command-line) and I want to be able to extract the package name until .el7

`x=dbus-sharp` (an example package name - which changes)

example text file:

```
Building dbus-sharp-0.7.0-11.fc22 for epel7
Created task: 7970206
...
0 free  1 open  1 done  0 failed
  7970225 buildArch (dbus-sharp-0.7.0-11.el7.src.rpm, ppc64): free
  7970223 buildArch (dbus-sharp-0.7.0-11.el7.src.rpm, x86_64): open (buildhw-03.phx2.fedoraproject.org)
...
```

basically now I want

```
y=dbus-sharp-0.7.0-11.el7
```

It doesn't matter if I need to use grep, sed or awk.

I haven't had any luck googling for a similar solution.

Examples I have tried:

```
[me@h dbus-sharp]$ echo "Here is a String" | grep -Po '(?<=(Here )).*(?= String)'
is a

[me@h dbus-sharp]$ cat scratchdbus-sharp | grep -Po '(?<=(dbus)).*(?= el7)'
(no output?)

[me@h dbus-sharp]$ cat scratchdbus-sharp | awk '/dbus/,/el7/'
(it dumps the whole text file?)

[me@h dbus-sharp]$ sed -n "/dbus/,/el7/p" scratchdbus-sharp
(again the whole text file is dumped)

[me@h dbus-sharp]$ grep -m 1 "dbus-sharp" scratchdbus-sharp 
Building dbus-sharp-0.7.0-11.fc22 for epel7
```

Guess I should also note that **ep**el7 will be in the text file(s) which will also cause a match for 'el7' complicating things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `grep` solution:

```
grep -m 1 -oP 'dbus[^ ]+\.el7' file
```

`-m 1` prints only one match, `-o` only the matching part and -P uses Perl regex.

And a `sed` solution:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(dbus.*\.el7\).*/\1/p' file | head -1
```

Removes all before and after `dbus.*el7` and prints it (`p`), but only the first match (`head -1`).

Comment: I got it to work like this: `grep -m 1 -oP $(echo $x)'[^ ]+\.el7' scratchgio-sharp` Can you please explain how you figured out to use this [^ ]+\ ? Or what [^ ]+\ does? Thanks.

Comment: @quickbooks sure, `[^ ]+` means that there are characters between, that are not `^` a space `\ `. The `+` means there are at least one or more of them. I use that because the epel7 line is also found. But with the point before `el7` -> `.el7` it should be enough, that should work too: `grep -m 1 -oP 'dbus.*\.el7' file`

Comment: Thanks for explaining what ` [^ ]+ ` means. Yes, `grep -m 1 -oP $(echo $x)'.*\.el7' scratch$x` also works. In the alternative solution where you used sed, can you please explain how you figured out that  s/.*\ and .*/\1/ will remove everything before and after the stuff in the brackets? Or what s/.*\ and .*/\1/ means? Thanks again.

Comment: @quickbooks in the sed command s means search and replace. Search for what is between the first 2 slashes and replace it with what is between slash 2 and 3. `.*` means match everything, the part in the brackets () is what we look for followed by .* (everything again). So we replace the whole line with \1. \1 means the subpattern that is inside the brackets (). The p at the end stands for print.